# How to create windowed multivariate dataset from SequenceExample TFRecord

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to set up a Tensorflow pipeline using tf.data.datasets in order to load some TFRecord into a Keras model. These data are multivariate timeseries.

I am currently using Tensorflow 2.0

First I get my dataset from the TFRecord and parse it :

```py
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('...')

context_features = {...}
sequence_features = {...}

def _parse_function(example_proto):
  _, sequence =  tf.io.parse_single_sequence_example(example_proto,context_features, sequence_features)
  return sequence


dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
```

The problem right now is that it gives me a MapDataset with dict of EagerTensor inside :

```py
for data in dataset.take(3):
  print(type(data))

<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>

# which look like : {feature1 : EagerTensor, feature2 : EagerTensor ...}
```

Because of these dictionaries, I cannot seem to manage to get these data to be batched, shuffled ... in order to use them in an LSTM layer afterwards. For instance this :

```py
def make_window_dataset(ds, window_size=5, shift=1, stride=1):
  windows = ds.window(window_size, shift=shift, stride=stride)

  def sub_to_batch(sub):
    return sub.values().batch(window_size, drop_remainder=True)

  windows = windows.flat_map(sub_to_batch)
  return windows

ds = make_window_dataset(dataset, 10)

gives me :

AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'batch'
```

Thank you for your help. I am basing my research on this and other Tensorflow helpers :

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#time_series_windowing

**EDIT :**

I found the solution to my problem. I ended up converting the dictionary given by the parsing to a (None,11) shaped Tensor using stack in my parse function :

```py
def _parse_function(example_proto):
  # Parse the input `tf.Example` proto using the dictionary above.
  _, sequence =  tf.io.parse_single_sequence_example(example_proto,context_features, sequence_features)
  return tf.stack(list(sequence.values()), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the question section, for the benefit of the community.

Converting dictionary to a tensor with shape `(None,11)` using `tf.stack` in the ***parse_function*** has resolved the problem.

Change code from

```
def _parse_function(example_proto):
  _, sequence =  tf.io.parse_single_sequence_example(example_proto,context_features, sequence_features)
  return sequence
```

to

```
def _parse_function(example_proto):
  _, sequence =  tf.io.parse_single_sequence_example(example_proto,context_features, sequence_features)
  return tf.stack(list(sequence.values()), axis=1)
```